# Ошибка при запуске веб-камеры Opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Не могу открыть веб камеру,хотя предзаписанные видео все же запускает,если прописать путь.

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,600)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)
while True:
    _,img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('test',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:  # ESC или закончились кадры
        break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Выводит такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать чтобы починить?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте установить ширину не в  600, а 640

Comment: @AlexAlex та же ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение.

```py
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```